# epoch convert json int (unix timestamp) into readable date in swift

Tags: json, swift, unix-timestamp, epoch

I'm creating a weather app based on OpenWeatherMap APIs in Swift.

I receive the local time via Unix Timestamp as an Int and I would like to convert it into a human-readable format.

I can convert current (device) time into a readable format, but not an int value.

Answer (score 4):

As you are using `Codable` it's pretty easy

- Declare all struct members related to dates (`dt`, `sunrise`, `sunset`) as `Date`

  ```
  let dt : Date
  ```
- Add the appropriate date decoding strategy to the decoder

  ```
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
  ```
- Use `DateFormatter` to get a human readable string for example

  ```
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMMddHHmmss")
  let dateString = formatter.string(from: dt)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get this error on the line let dateString = formatter.string(from: dt) `Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>?) -> time_t' (aka '(Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>>) -> Int') to expected argument type 'Date'`

Comment: Did you follow all steps in the answer?

Comment: I'm using `OpenWeatherMap` myself in a few projects. Decoding the UNIX timestamps as `Date` is supposed to work. And `dt` is sent always. Don't declare it as optional.

Comment: I'm not using OpenWeatherMap for the local time tho. I use OWM to display temperature, weather and name of the city. Through the same APIs I also gather the coordinates that I use to create the DarkSky Link to the same city (OWM uses the name of the city, DarkSky uses the coordinates) to gather the local time. `struct MyLocalTime: Decodable {
    let currently: Currently
}`

`struct Currently: Decodable {
    let time: Date
}` this is the code of the struct.

Comment: I don't know `DarkSky`. My suggestion is only valid for OWM.

Comment: Instead this is the parsing process: `do {
                        let forecast = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyLocalTime.self, from: data!)
                        
                        
                        let timeDecoder = JSONDecoder()
                        timeDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
                        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        timeFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyyMMMddHHmmss")
                        let dateAsString = formatter.string(from: time)`

Comment: unfortunately OWM does not support local time.

Comment: It does. All date values are in UTC, but the output of the date formatter is in local time.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was adding 31 years and 1 day to my datetimes and I was a little confused

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamps are usually either seconds or milliseconds since midnight on 1 January, 1970.

It's pretty easy to convert a Cocoa `Date` to Unix milliseconds:

```
let unixMilliseconds: Int = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
print(unixMilliseconds)
```

Or, if you have a Unix timestamp:

```
let date = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: Double(unixMilliseconds/1000))
print(DateFormatter.localizedString(from: date, dateStyle: .medium, timeStyle: .medium))
```

(If you're dealing with seconds you can just get ride of the `*1000` and `/1000` in the code above. Or use a JSON decoder as described in vadian's excellent answer.)